# Error installing hubot on Windows

Tags: node.js, hubot

I am installing hubot on Windows. I read the instructions from github hubot repository, but when I tried the command `bin/hubot` I get the following error

```
$ node node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee bin/hubot
connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm mo
dule instead node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser
.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read node_modules
\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:86:15
Hubot> [Mon Dec 01 2014 14:22:31 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)] ERRO
R Error: listen EACCES
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
  at listen (net.js:1064:10)
  at net.js:1146:9
  at dns.js:72:18
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

**edit**

When I shutdown Apacheserver, I got the following error

```
$ bin/hubot --disable-httpd
npm WARN package.json hubot-maps@0.0.0 No repository field.
connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm mo
dule instead node_modules\hubot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\mi
ddleware\bodyParser.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read node_modules
\hubot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:86:
15
Hubot> [Mon Dec 01 2014 15:32:12 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)] ERRO
R Error: listen EACCES
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
  at listen (net.js:1064:10)
  at net.js:1146:9
  at dns.js:72:18
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)

[Mon Dec 01 2014 15:32:13 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)] ERROR hubot
-heroku-alive included, but missing HUBOT_HEROKU_KEEPALIVE_URL. `heroku config:s
et HUBOT_HEROKU_KEEPALIVE_URL=$(heroku apps:info -s  | grep web_url | cut -d= -f
2)`
[Mon Dec 01 2014 15:32:13 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)] INFO Using
default redis on localhost:6379
```

Comment: You most likely have IIS running on port 80.  

Try running hubot with the --disable-httpd flag.

Comment: I'm working with xampp. I just down apache server, but I got the following error:

Comment: I shutdown the Tomcat server running in port 8080 and HUbot is now live. How can I change the port to work with both Hubot and TomcatServer

Comment: set an env variable for the port you want to use.  https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/c9f0bb4fcf7b285aaa929524e8ad8172500e4411/src/robot.coffee#L287